# How do i run this program i am new to oops

Tags: python, class, object

Can anyone help me out with this program please, I am beginner

[image]

Comment: what program? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no init function

Comment: Hi, please upload your code that can be coppied

Comment: You forgot parenthesis in `enemy = Enemy()`. Just so you know code should be posted as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, I forgot parenthesis, code is working now and I will keep in mind that next time I post the code as a text, not an image, Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be you forgot parentheses after creating `enemy1`.

```
class Enemy:
    life = 3

    def attack(self):
        print('ouch')
        self.life -= 1 # notice the - signs comes before the equal sign

    def checklife(self):
        if self.life <= 0:
            print('i am dead')
        else:
            print(str(self.life) + ' life left') # notice where ' ` ` life left' comes


enemy1 = Enemy() # added parantheses after `Enemy`
enemy1.attack()
enemy1.checklife()
```

And remember, it is much better to post the code as text rather than a picture.